# Conventions for naming a class containg common methods used in all application

Tags: c#, naming, conventions

I have Xamarin.Android application with 8 activities. In each activity I create 2,3 or more methods which has nothing in common for example in my `SynchronizationActivity` I have created two methods `UnzipFile` and `ImportXMLFileIntoDatabase` in my other activities I have created another methods. I don't want my methods to be in the activity to make it clearer so I want to put all methods my activities use in a single static class as static methods and in the activity I want to use them like that:

```
Helper.UnzipFile() or Helper.ImportXMLFileIntoDatabase()
```

I cave created the Helper class in a folder named CommonMethods. Can someone think of better name for class and folder and is there any C# naming convention for that?

Comment: How about foldername "Helper" and class name "XMLHelper" or "FileHelper"? or instead of "Helper" take the word "Manager". I see this often

Comment: Not every method of mine will work with files or xml. So you think if I call my folder "Helper" and my class "Manager" it will be fine?

Comment: From my experience, i've seen this alot. It's more like a suggestion. You might also fight something else, something that you can get used to and that you personally like might be a very important aspect as well

Comment: I don't think there's a name that hits the spot, for "a bunch of unrelated methods". Personally I tend to use what I have and move on, hoping that some day these methods find a better home.

Comment: sounds like a "god type" to me (note: this isn't a good thing...)

Comment: UnzipFile could be an extension method. If you need this for more than one type then it could be moved to a class `FileUnzipper`(?) with a method name `Unzip()`. `ImportXMLFileIntoDatabase` could be in a class `FileImporter` and I would rename the method to `ImportXml()`.

Answer (score 1):

Naming classes is hard but it becomes even more difficult when your class has no clear purpose. I would suggest looking into the [SOLID design principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). The S stands for Single Responsibility which means that a class should have only one responsibility, one reason to exist and only one reason to change.

If your Helper class has just a bunch of methods where some work with files and others do completely unrelated things, you're violating SOLID. And violating SOLID makes it difficult to name things.

It's true that you will see things like Manager and Helper classes a lot in the wild but that doesn't make it a good practice to follow. Having such generic class names doesn't help in building good and maintainable code.

Try to group your methods in such a way that the class containing them has a Single Responsibility. Naming them will be much easier after that. You're already doing this by recognizing these methods don't belong in your Xamarin Acitivies which is a good thing! Just take it a step further to make things even better.

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation
>   and naming things.
>
> -- Phil Karlton

Comment: This is 100%, but sometimes it is just annoying to create 3 separate classes just because you have 3 separate methods that do different things. Then you have to create interfaces for each class and mock them if you use TDD. Then it turns out it is difficult to mock one of them, so you make a factory and interface for it and you end up with 8 files, because of 3 methods...

Comment: @FCin agreed. We sometimes takes this to far. A 'trick' to avoid interface explosion for mocking is to describe the methods as a Action or Func and inject these in your class. You can then easily replace them when testing.